# How to add an array of objects in Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

can someone help me?

I'm trying to update my Mongoose Schema and add to it an Array like this :
I want to add to my ProductSchema the "attribute" ( I don't know how we call this, sorry ^^') description and in this description, you have multiple attributes lile brand, model, size, color, ...

I did something like this but (I don't think it worked) :

```
...
    description: [
        { brand: String },
        { model: String },
        { size: String },
        { color: String },
        { year: Number },
        { State: String }
    ]
...
```

Thank's for your time !

**UPDATE:**

In fact, I don't need an array for the description, that was a stupid question ^^'

I can do something like this :

```
...
    description: {
        brand: String,
        model: String,
        size: String,
        color: String,
        year: Number,
        State: String
    }
...
```

Comment: You can use "property" instead of "attribute" if you find it more explicit.

Comment: thank's for the precision !

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you don't need an [array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#arrays) if there is only one "decription" in your document schema.

However, if you need to store multiple descriptions, you can use :

```
...
description: [{
    brand: String,
    model: String,
    size: String,
    color: String,
    year: Number,
    State: String
}]
```

In your first attempt, you've made each property of your object an object itself.